# Insert a specific id into auto incremented field in MySQL with Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

So this i my situation.

I have an old database with a lot, and I mean a LOT of data. However I've ended up creating a new database structure and now I want to move data from the old database into the new one. Being a programmer I'm not keen on doing it manually which is why I made a program to do just that.

Now here is my problem: When adding a new item into the new database I'm unable to set it's id, which is crucial for the different link references and general foreign key references that exists in the old database.

My question is therefore: How would I be able to insert an *specified id* integer into a field that has **auto_increment** in my **MySQL** database via **Entity Framework 5** which uses database first in **C#**?

This is my MySQL script for the new database:

```
    CREATE TABLE Profile
    (
        _id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        UNIQUE KEY(_id),
        etc etc
    )
```

My insert code:

```
    public Profile Add(Profile item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("item");
        }

        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Added;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return item;
    }
```

On an end note I whould like to inform that I know this is bad practise in general, but the database is empty and the id inserted are auto generated and unique from the old database which will ensure that no dublicates will occour

Comment: Set 'IDENTITY_INSERT ON' on your table before adding new item.

Comment: @aria If I remember right and from what I can find around the net the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT Profile ON` is a **MSSQL** specific command and doesn't work with **MySQL**

Comment: I am not familiar with MySql but I read somewhere MySQL lets you manually insert values into an AUTO_INCREMENT column and this is already allowed.

Comment: @aria: I read the same thing ^^ however I was unable to until I changed the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS`

Comment: So accept your answer as your answer !

Comment: @aria: Sorry I forgot, you couldn't accept it until after two days ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found where to alter the table before inserting into it. It's basicly the solution other people gave, however I needed to make a few turns.

This is what I did:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

ALTER TABLE Profile DROP PRIMARY KEY,
MODIFY _id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL;

insert commmand here....

ALTER TABLE Profile DROP PRIMARY KEY,
MODIFY _id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to turn off identity insert, insert the records then turn on identity insert back

Comment: From what I can find on the net the Identity_Insert is a **MSSQL** command and won't work with **MySQL**

Answer (score 1):

I came into the same problem except using **Entity Framework 6**, this is how I solved it:

1. Go into your Entity Model
2. Select each auto_increment field and in properties set **StoreGeneratedPattern** to **None**