# Can't alter table to remove auto_increment due to foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to remove **Auto_Increment** from the `column` _id in my **MySQL** database. However that `column` is the `primary key` for the table and when I'm using this command

```
ALTER TABLE Profile
MODIFY _id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
```

I get an error telling me that I can't do that since there are other tables which references the `primary key`.

My question is therefore: Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Remove the foreign key(s) from other table, alter your table and recreate the forreign key(s).

Comment: `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` enable it when you`re done But primary key and auto increment are almost synonyms why do you want to do that?

Comment: @Mihai: It is as a possible solution to this problem I have

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887585/insert-a-specific-id-into-auto-incremented-field-in-mysql-with-entity-framework

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I temporarily disable a foreign key constraint in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15501673/how-can-i-temporarily-disable-a-foreign-key-constraint-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thre options:

1.Delete relationship before making this change.

2.Delete other table/s before making this change.

3.Alter relationship(tables) with somthing like on update / cascade (not sure if this will help)

Comment: Will there be a way to delete relations without losing data the related tables?

Comment: I ended up using Mihai's solution with setting the foreign key checks to zero and then back to one after inserting the wanted value

Answer (score 14):

the easiest and fastest way is the following:

```
set foreign_key_checks = 0;
alter table Profile change column _id _id INT NOT NULL;
set foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90162/adding-autoincrement-to-id-already-part-of-foreign-key)

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it.